# Unresponsive JQuery Script when Ajax is called and Data returned is in chinese (zho) language

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mozilla

I have a website working on multiple language. 
However when Chinese language is selected and Ajax is called the Browser gets hanged for a while and **JQUERY is unresponsive** and gives an alert saying

**"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
Script: jquery.min.js:3"**

This issue occurs when the json data has some Chinese text else the site works fine from English, French, German, etc.

Any idea why does this happen ?